# Standalone Wear OS watchface without Android app

Tags: android, wear-os, watchface

I have a standalone Xamarin Watchface for Tizen and I want to bring it over to Wear OS - is it possible? Without any companion app (e.g. no Android app)? When I try to add an app on Google Play it requires "phone" and "tablet" screenshots before even asking for app type. What kind of screenshots should I provide in such case?

Comment: The screenshots for phone and tablet are for people viewing your app listing on a phone or tablet. It doesn't mean that your app has to support these devices.

Comment: And yes, you can create applications for Wear OS that doesn't require a companion app (or a paired phone at all). More details can be found in the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps